# Attaching square root $p$ and cube root $p$ to a ring $R = \mathbb{Z}/(p^{k}\mathbb{Z})$, assuming it is not in $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}/(p^{k}\mathbb{Z})$, be a ring and $p$ be any prime number, and $k > 3$ be any integer. Then is $R[x,y]/\langle x^2 - p , y^3 - p \rangle$ isomorphic to the ring $R[p^{1/2},p^{1/3}]$? I want to attach square root $p$ and cube  root $p$ in this ring  $R = \mathbb{Z}/p^{k}\mathbb{Z}$

My idea is if we choose a ring homomorphism $\phi : R[x,y] \to R[p^{1/2},p^{1/3}]$ by $\phi(x) = p^{1/2}$, $\phi(y) = p^{1/3}$ and $\phi(r)=r ~\forall r \in R$, it is easy to see that $\langle x^2 - p, y^3 - p \rangle \subseteq \ker(\phi)$. But can we show that $\ker(\phi) \subseteq \langle x^2 - p, y^3 - p \rangle ?$

Comment: -1 The claim is just patently false. Also consider a more descriptive title.

Comment: OP asks a genuine question, and has shown his work, he should be downvoted based on the result being true or not

Comment: Please give a definition of $R[p^{1/2},p^{1/3}]$. In which ring do you take this extension? And what is known about $R$? In general, as already commented, the claim will be false. Take $R = \mathbb{F}_p$ for example. Please specify the **complete context** of the question.

Comment: You didn't answer the first of my questions. Which is if course the most important one. You need to define the object that you are asking for.

Comment: I think $R[p^{1/2},p^{1/3}]$ is the smallest ring containing R, $p^{1/2}$ and $p^{1/3}$.

Comment: The notion "smallest ring" doesn't exist. You have to specify a ring in which you want the smallest **subring** containing these elements (and $R$). Please read about ring and field adjunctions.